# AFNetworking and soap with session

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, session, soap

I need to connect to soap web service. I have never done this, and as much as I understand, I need to create session using `user_name` and `user_password`. When session is successful i need to download some `JSON` objects. I have chose `AFNetworking` for this kind of web service, but it seems google cant help me, because i don't know where to start. Can someone help me?

I have tried to create session using `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, and response was good but how to continue? How to download what i want?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/622376/iOS-Soap-Webservice-Calling-and-Parsing-the-Resp check here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch all the data from your `json` object like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website/url"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // Here you are parsing your data
    // The following sample fetch data from:
    // {
    //     status: 1
    //     array: {
    //         user: "user";
    //         password: "password";
    //     }
    // }
    NSDictionary *fullResponse = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    fullResponse = responseObject;

    if ([[fullResponse objectForKey:@"status"] intValue]  == 1) {
        NSDictionary *array = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        array = [fullResponse objectForKey:@"array"];

        NSString *userName = [array objectForKey:@"user"];
        NSString *userPassword = [array objectForKey:@"password"];     
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

}];

[operation start];
```

Also notice that if your json object contain any `array`, you should store them in `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) instead of `NSDictionary`.